# Add column from df2 to df1 based on match between df1 and df2

Tags: r

I have two data sets df1 and df2, which have one column "ID" and "Country" in common:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:20), State=c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","CA","IL","SD","NC","SC","WA","CO","AL","AK","HI"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,"NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), Year=c("2020","2021","2020","2020","2021","2020","2020","2021","2020","2019"),State=c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","CA","SC","NY","NJ","OR"))
```

How can I add Year from df2 to df1 to the same ID that exists in df1 OR the same State that exists in df1?

The reason why I want to make this change: I just need to add this "Year" information from df2 to df1.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df1 <- type.convert(df1)
df2 <- type.convert(df2)

df1 %>%
    left_join(select(df2, -State), 'ID') %>%
    left_join(select(filter(df2, is.na(ID)), -ID), 'State') %>%
    mutate(Year = coalesce(Year.x, Year.y), Year.x = NULL, Year.y = NULL)

   ID State Year
1   1  <NA> 2020
2   2  <NA> 2021
3   3  <NA> 2020
4   4  <NA> 2020
5   5  <NA> 2021
6   6  <NA>   NA
7   7  <NA>   NA
8   8  <NA>   NA
9   9  <NA>   NA
10 10  <NA>   NA
11 11    CA 2020
12 12    IL   NA
13 13    SD   NA
14 14    NC   NA
15 15    SC 2020
16 16    WA   NA
17 17    CO   NA
18 18    AL   NA
19 19    AK   NA
20 20    HI   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(join = ifelse(State == 'NA', ID, State))

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(join = ifelse(State == 'NA', ID, State))

df_new <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "join") %>% 
  mutate(State = coalesce(State.x, State.y)) %>% 
  select(-c(State.x, State.y, join, ID.y)) %>% 
  rename(ID = ID.x)
```

This gives us:

```
   ID Year State
1   1 2020    NA
2   2 2021    NA
3   3 2020    NA
4   4 2020    NA
5   5 2021    NA
6   6 <NA>    NA
7   7 <NA>    NA
8   8 <NA>    NA
9   9 <NA>    NA
10 10 <NA>    NA
11 11 2020    CA
12 12 <NA>    IL
13 13 <NA>    SD
14 14 <NA>    NC
15 15 2020    SC
16 16 <NA>    WA
17 17 <NA>    CO
18 18 <NA>    AL
19 19 <NA>    AK
20 20 <NA>    HI
```